# Transfer props to children without re-rendering parent

Tags: reactjs

Is there a React-okay way to pass new props to children without re-rendering the parent? Nothing in the parent component is changing except that new props are being passed to that component which are being passed through to its children. I thought context might be appropriate in this situation but it seems like the documentation states otherwise.

Comment: what? the whole point of props is to be passed from the parent to the child. you dont re render the parent. if the data changes for the child.. but not the parent... it isn't re rendered. thats the whole point of reacts virtual dom.

Comment: By "re-rendering", I'm assuming you mean calling the `render()` function again. If not then you have nothing to worry about thanks to the virtual DOM. Anyway, you could use flux/redux, but that can be messy too.  Or it might make sense to have some sort of callback function that updates the internal state of the child component. It's hard to think of any legitimate reason not to call `render()` multiple times though. It should be idempotent and is rarely slow. If performance is an issue, look into `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by React-okay. You can in fact use [contexts](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) for this, but I don't recommend it. It's much easier to reason about and debug props flowing down directly through your view hierarchy, and if the parent isn't changing at all the render function should be quite cheap to execute.

If it isn't cheap, you may want to rethink how you're structuring your components. For example, you may want to split off the expensive part into a separate component that only gets rendered when relevant props have actually changed, or at least secure the expensive functionality behind a conditional props check.